# Socket.io with npm on windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm, engine.io

I wan't to install socket.io with npm 2.7.4, node 0.12.2 on  windows 8.1 & get this error:

> modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(518): error C4430: missing type specifier - in
>       t assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\so
>       cket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.v
>       cxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(490): error C2065: 'request' : undeclared iden
>       tifier [C:...\websocket\no
>       de_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-clien
>       t\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(490): error C2228: left of '.data' must have c
>       lass/struct/union [C:...\w
>       ebsocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engi
>       ne.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 type is ''unknown-type''
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(529): error C2039: 'NewSymbol' : is not a memb
>       er of 'v8::String' [C:...\
>       websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\eng
>       ine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 C:....node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see decl
>         aration of 'v8::String'
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(529): error C3861: 'NewSymbol': identifier not
>        found [C:...\websocket\no
>       de_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-clien
>       t\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(536): error C2039: 'NewSymbol' : is not a memb
>       er of 'v8::String' [C:...\
>       websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\eng
>       ine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 C:\Users....node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see decl
>         aration of 'v8::String'
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(536): error C2228: left of '.As' must have cla
>       ss/struct/union [C:...\web
>       socket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine
>       .io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(536): error C2059: syntax error : ')' [C:...\websocket\node_modules\sock
>       et.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\
>       ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(549): error C2039: 'New' : is not a member of
>       'v8::String' [C:...\websoc
>       ket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io
>       -client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 C:....node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see decl
>         aration of 'v8::String'
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(550): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of
>        constant size 0 [C:...\we
>       bsocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engin
>       e.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(550): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot con
>       vert from 'int' to 'v8::Local' [C:...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\n
>       ode_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 with
>                 [
>                     T=v8::Value
>                 ]
>                 No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload re
>         solution was ambiguous
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(549): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found
>        [C:...\websocket\node_mod
>       ules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node
>       _modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(555): error C2065: 'uv_work_t' : undeclared id
>       entifier [C:...\websocket\
>       node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cli
>       ent\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(555): error C2065: 'req' : undeclared identifi
>       er [C:...\websocket\node_m
>       odules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\no
>       de_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(555): error C2448: 'NanAsyncExecute' : functio
>       n-style initializer appears to be a function definition [C:\Users...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modu
>       les\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\valida
>       tion.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(560): error C2065: 'uv_work_t' : undeclared id
>       entifier [C:...\websocket\
>       node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cli
>       ent\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(560): error C2065: 'req' : undeclared identifi
>       er [C:...\websocket\node_m
>       odules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\no
>       de_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(560): error C2448: 'NanAsyncExecuteComplete' :
>        function-style initializer appears to be a function definition [C:\Users...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\n
>       ode_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\buil
>       d\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(570): error C2039: 'request' : is not a member
>        of 'NanAsyncWorker' [C:...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\e
>       ngine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 C:...\websocket\
>         node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-c
>         lient\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(487) : see declaration of 'NanAs
>         yncWorker'
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(571): error C2065: 'NanAsyncExecute' : undecla
>       red identifier [C:...\webs
>       ocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.
>       io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(571): error C2065: 'uv_after_work_cb' : undecl
>       ared identifier [C:...\web
>       socket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine
>       .io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(572): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')'
>       before identifier 'NanAsyncExecuteComplete' [C:\Users...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.i
>       o-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj
>       ]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(572): error C2059: syntax error : ')' [C:...\websocket\node_modules\sock
>       et.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\
>       ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(716): error C2661: 'v8::Local::New' : no ov
>       erloaded function takes 1 arguments [C:...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client
>       \node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 with
>                 [
>                     T=v8::String
>                 ]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(769): error C2039: 'AsciiValue' : is not a mem
>       ber of 'v8::String' [C:...
>       \websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\en
>       gine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 C:....node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see decl
>         aration of 'v8::String'
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(769): error C2065: 'AsciiValue' : undeclared i
>       dentifier [C:...\websocket
>       \node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cl
>       ient\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(769): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
>       before identifier 'value' [C:...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modu
>       les\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(769): error C3861: 'value': identifier not fou
>       nd [C:...\websocket\node_m
>       odules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\no
>       de_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(817): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion f
>       rom 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.
>       io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxpro
>       j]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(829): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion f
>       rom 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.
>       io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxpro
>       j]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(832): error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identi
>       fier [C:...\websocket\node
>       _modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>       node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(840): error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identi
>       fier [C:...\websocket\node
>       _modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>       node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(840): error C2228: left of '.length' must have
>        class/struct/union [C:...
>       \websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\en
>       gine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 type is ''unknown-type''
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(858): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion f
>       rom 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.
>       io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxpro
>       j]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(873): error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identi
>       fier [C:...\websocket\node
>       _modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\
>       node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       C:...\websocket\node_modul
>       es\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_m
>       odules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(873): error C2228: left of '.length' must have
>        class/struct/union [C:...
>       \websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\en
>       gine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 type is ''unknown-type''
>       ..\src\validation.cc(108): error C2248: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope' : cannot
>        access protected member declared in class 'v8::HandleScope' [C:...\websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node
>       _modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\v
>       alidation.vcxproj]
>                 C:....node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(816) : see decla
>         ration of 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope'
>                 C:....node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(800) : see decla
>         ration of 'v8::HandleScope'
>       ..\src\validation.cc(109): error C2664: 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New' : cannot co
>       nvert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo &)'
>       to 'v8::Isolate *' [C:...\
>       websocket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\eng
>       ine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 with
>                 [
>                     T=v8::Value
>                 ]
>                 There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>       ..\src\validation.cc(112): error C2039: 'NewSymbol' : is not a member of 'v8::S
>       tring' [C:...\websocket\no
>       de_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-clien
>       t\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>                 C:....node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) : see decl
>         aration of 'v8::String'
>       ..\src\validation.cc(112): error C3861: 'NewSymbol': identifier not found [C:...\websocket\node_modules\s
>       ocket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modul
>       es\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       ..\src\validation.cc(134): error C2660: 'v8::True' : function does not take 0 a
>       rguments [C:...\websocket\
>       node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cli
>       ent\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       ..\src\validation.cc(134): error C2660: 'v8::False' : function does not take 0
>       arguments [C:...\websocket
>       \node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-cl
>       ient\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]
>       socket.io@1.3.5 node_modules\socket.io
>       ├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
>       ├── has-binary-data@0.1.3 (isarray@0.0.1)
>       ├── socket.io-adapter@0.3.1 (object-keys@1.0.1, debug@1.0.2, socket.io-parser@2.
>       2.2)
>       ├── socket.io-parser@2.2.4 (isarray@0.0.1, debug@0.7.4, component-emitter@1.1.2,
>        benchmark@1.0.0, json3@3.2.6)
>       ├── engine.io@1.5.1 (base64id@0.1.0, debug@1.0.3, engine.io-parser@1.2.1, ws@0.5
>       .0)
>       └── socket.io-client@1.3.5 (to-array@0.1.3, indexof@0.0.1, component-bind@1.0.0,
>        debug@0.7.4, backo2@1.0.2, object-component@0.0.3, component-emitter@1.1.2, has
>       -binary@0.1.6, parseuri@0.0.2, engine.io-client@1.5.1)

## See solution in comments

Comment: npm uses node-gyp to compile native C stuff, what compiler do you have for that?  Any Visual Studio installed?

Comment: I already had those "compiler not found" errors, so i installed visual studio 2012 express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had some help on github, you can check the temporary solution there https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/2072

Comment: I cannot find the folder specified in that post:  `node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules` where do I find it?

Comment: What package are you trying to use? He is using the browser-sync package I suppose. In my case the folder was `MYAPP\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_mo‌​dules`